# How to display data as KB, MB, GB, TB on y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, data-visualization

I am drawing a chart which is displaying traffic volume on server. I want to display units as KB, MB etc on y axis. Any opinion how can I do this via d3 axis scales.

Comment: Could you give more detail please on exactly how you want this to look.  Do you want KB and MB on the same axis?  Is the scale linear?  Do you want KB on values only up to a certain threshold?

Comment: I want a linear scale. Ideally KB and MB should not be on same scale, Yes we can have thresholds on values, to obtain uniform scale on all values. An example is , If highest traffic volume in data is 150KB, the resultant scale on y axis could be like 0 KB, 50 KB, 100 KB, 150 KB

Comment: It is near to my solution but not solved it completly. My requirement is to create a linear scale for that, like I described in above comment.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using the [`d3.tickFormat` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat): [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ysh48/1/).

```js
var bytesToString = function (bytes) {
    // One way to write it, not the prettiest way to write it.

    var fmt = d3.format('.0f');
    if (bytes < 1024) {
        return fmt(bytes) + 'B';
    } else if (bytes < 1024 * 1024) {
        return fmt(bytes / 1024) + 'kB';
    } else if (bytes < 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
        return fmt(bytes / 1024 / 1024) + 'MB';
    } else {
        return fmt(bytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) + 'GB';
    }
}

var xScale = d3.scale.log()
               .domain([1, Math.pow(2, 40)])
               .range([0, 480]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .orient('left')
                .tickFormat(bytesToString)
                .tickValues(d3.range(11).map(
                    function (x) { return Math.pow(2, 4 * x); }
                ));
```

You will also want to use your own values for the `tickValues` as well, though.